# How can I extract a single value of a html table in Python?

Tags: python, html, sqlite, beautifulsoup, lxml

I want to save data from a table, which has been scraped from a website, into a SQLite Database. Here is what I was able to do so far. Preferrably i want to save a value into a variably and later load it into the database.

```
import requests
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.boerse.de/historische-kurse/Daimler-Aktie/DE0007100000")

# storing content of page
src = response.content

# create BeatifulSoup Object based on src
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

tables = soup.find_all("tr")


"""for table in tables:
    if "17.03.20" in table.text:
        table = table.text
        table = etree.HTML(table)
        rows = iter(table)
        for row in rows:
            values = [col.text for col in row]
            print(values)"""

for table in tables:
    if "17.03.20" in table.text:
        print(table)
```

Comment: so what's your question? What are you trying to extract? What is your expected output here?

Comment: If you look at the website, i want to have the first column/value for the date 17.03.20 (first row in table) saved in a variable and later put into a SQLite Database.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get("https://www.boerse.de/historische-kurse/Daimler-Aktie/DE0007100000")

# storing content of page
src = response.content

# create BeatifulSoup Object based on src
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'html.parser')

tables = soup.find_all("table")

for table in tables:
    if "17.03.20" in table.text:
        df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
        row = df[df['Datum'] == "17.03.20"]

print (row)
```

**Output:**

```
print (row)
      Datum Erster Schluss    Hoch Tief  ... Schluss Volumen Veränderung Veränderung
0  17.03.20    23,77 23,98  24,81 21,57  ...    2398     4.290.555 5,64%       5,64%

[1 rows x 7 columns]
```

[image]

**To check if date is a Sunday:**

You need to convert the string to datetime object. Then you can either, convert into a string that states the day of the week. Or check for the numerical value (6 is for Sunday)

```
import datetime

dateStr = '17.03.20'
date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateStr, '%d.%m.%y')


print (date_object.strftime('%A'))
print (date_object.weekday()) # Sunday = 6, Saturday = 5
```

**Output:**

```
Tuesday
1
```

Comment: And how do i get the 23,77 for example into a variable?

Comment: value = row.loc[0,'Erster Schluss'].split()[0]

Comment: What is the 'Erster Schluss' for? If i want the column next to it 'Schluss' should be the indicator right?

Comment: It's little tricky here. Normally, you would be correct, but how the html is layed out, and since you were asking for `23,77`. `Erster Schuluss` is how pandas parsed the table (see image in solution above). It needs to be split. to get the first value `23,77` you want index position [0] of that split, and the second value of `23,98`, you'd use index position [1] on that split.

Comment: Ah ok thank got it. And how do i get from other dates? 17.03.20 seems to be the only one to work now. I cant just replace the date

Comment: `row = df[df['Datum'] == "<put date string in here>"].reset_index(drop=True)`  add the `.reset_index()` part

Comment: Duuude thank alot. Just one mor thing, have you got an idea how i can check if a date is a sunday or saturday? is theree something fast for that? Because shares dont change on weekends

Comment: @HendrikNiemax check solution above

Comment: I tried that but it saysdatetime and dateGivenStr are undefinded

Comment: try again. Had a typo